# Show that $3^n-2^n\cdot 5$ is composite for infinitely many $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I came across this problem:

Show that $3^n-2^n\cdot 5$ is composite for infinitely many $n$

and do not know how to solve it. I only know that it is true for $n=7$, since then $1547=17\cdot 91$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you already did most of the work. You know that $3^n-2^n\cdot5$ is divisible by $17$ for $n=7$.

Now, consider $n=16+7$. What does [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tell us?

Comment: You mean Fermat's little theorem? Wouldn't it then be $n=16+7$?

Comment: @user144248 Exactly. Very good that you saw my mistake!

Comment: @barto Great solution. How could I have found out without knowing that $17$ divides $3^7-5\cdot 2^7$?

Comment: I may be blind. Someone care to explain it in more details?

Comment: @Umberto Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yep... But maybe is late :) Need to take some paper and look into it... Trying to do everything without writing...

Comment: Well, Fermat's Little Theorem says that $2^{16}\equiv3^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$. Then for every $k\geqslant0$, $3^{7+16k}-2^{7+16k}\cdot5\equiv 3^7\cdot(3^{16})^k-2^7\cdot(2^{16})^k\cdot5\equiv3^7\cdot1^k-2^7\cdot1^k\cdot5=3^7-2^7\cdot5\equiv0\pmod{17}$.

Comment: @user144248 Note that, in fact we didn't have to calculate anything. We could simply solve this like: Take $m$ large enough so that $3^m-2^m\cdot5>1$, so it will have a prime divisor $p>3$. Then we can take $n=m+k\cdot(p-1)$ for every $k\geqslant0$, applying the same reasoning with FLT. Alternatively, note that $7\mid 3^1-2^1\cdot5$, which means $7\mid3^{6k+1}-2^{6k+1}\cdot5$ for every $k\geqslant0$.